# Can't Get Rid Of 8px Margin

Tags: html, css, angular

Having trouble getting rid of white space around my body element. I am setting margin and padding to 0 in both my css and html, but when I run the application the body has a margin of 8px. When I look in the developer tools it says the body styles is coming from User Agent Stylesheet. I think my problem has something to do with that. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}




/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
  background-color: #22aedc;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 60px;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav h2 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center, center;
  align-content: center, center;
  //padding: 4px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 21px;
  font: "Tahoma";
  overflow: hidden;
  }

footer {
  font: "Tahoma";
  font-size: 13px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

body {
  background-image: url('/Angular/src/assets/img/kraft.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-x: center;
  background-position-y: 330px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0;
}


.dv-panel {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background: #f6f8f9;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f6f8f9 0%, #e5ebee 50%, #d7dee3 51%, #f5f7f9 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f6f8f9 0%, #e5ebee 50%, #d7dee3 51%, #f5f7f9 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f6f8f9 0%, #e5ebee 50%, #d7dee3 51%, #f5f7f9 100%);
}


.dv-menuPanel {
  @extend .dv-panel;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  // Added 'row' class to make height match
  //  that of children
  //overflow: hidden;
  .dv-menuPanelContent {
    min-height: 300px;
    background: white;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);

    .menuPanelHeader {
      background: #5bc0de;
      color: white;

      h3 {
        padding: 10px;
        margin-top: 0;
      }
    }

    .menuPanelHeaderAlt {
      color: #555;

      h3 {
        padding: 10px;
        margin-top: 0;
        //font-size: 32px;
      }
    }

    .contentPanelHeaderAlt {
      color: #555;
    }
  }
}

.dv-panel, .dv-menuPanel, .dv-menuPanelAlt {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #f6f8f9;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f6f8f9 0%, #e5ebee 50%, #d7dee3 51%, #f5f7f9 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f6f8f9 0%, #e5ebee 50%, #d7dee3 51%, #f5f7f9 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f6f8f9 0%, #e5ebee 50%, #d7dee3 51%, #f5f7f9 100%);
}

.dv-panel {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background: #f6f8f9;
}

.dv-button {
  display: block;
  background-color: #5bc0de;
  border-color: #46b8da;
  padding: 17px 16px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  font: Tahoma;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.dv-button:hover {
  background-color: #EEE;
  color: black;
}

.db-button:active {
  background-color: aqua;
  color: white;
}

.plant-button {
  display: block;
  background-color: #5bc0de;
  border-color: #46b8da;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  font: Tahoma;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.plant-button:hover {
  background-color: #EEE;
  color: black;
}

.plant-button:active {
  background-color: aqua;
  color: white;
}

.pagination {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: white;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  color: grey;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  font: Tahoma;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-top: 40px;
}

.pagination:hover {
  background-color: #EEE;
  color: black;
}

.pagination:active {
  background-color: aqua;
  color: white;
}

#back {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #008cba;
  border-color: #0079a1;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  outline: none
}

#back:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

#back:active {
  background-color: #6e6d6f;
  color: white;
}

.import-header {
  display: block;
  background-color: #5bc0de;
  border-color: #46b8da;
  padding: 17px 16px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  font: Tahoma;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Angular/src/assets/css/fontawesome.min.css" />
</head>



<body style="background-color: lightgrey; width: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px">

  <div style="padding-top: 5px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px">
    <div class="topnav">
      <h2 style="text-align: center">Import</h2>
      <i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="!isTypeCollapsed" style="justify-content:center; padding-top: 155px; padding-bottom: 375px">
    <div class="dv-panel" style="width: 400px; margin: auto; padding-bottom: 2px">
      <div *ngFor="let type of types">
        <button (click)="togglePlants(type)" class="dv-button">
          {{type}}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="isPlantsCollapsed" style="justify-content:center; padding-top: 125px; padding-bottom: 129px">
    <div class="dv-panel" style="width: 400px; margin: auto; overflow: hidden; margin-left: 733px">
      <button (click)="toggleBack()" class="far fa-arrow-left" id="back"></button>
      <div *ngFor="let plant of plants">
        <button class="plant-button" (click)="hidePlants(plant)">{{ plant }}</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="isImportPageCollapsed" style="justify-content:center; padding-top: 165px; padding-bottom: 283px">
    <div class="dv-panel" style="width: 400px; height: 300px; margin: auto; padding-bottom: 100px; background-color: #f9f9f9">
      <button (click)="toggleBackFromImportPage()" class="far fa-arrow-left" id="back"></button>
      <button (click)="toggleHome()" class="far fa-home" id="back" style="margin-left: -9px"></button>
      <div>
        <button class="import-header">
          {{ importPlant }} ~ {{importType}}
        </button>

        <div class="form-group" style="width: 370px; margin: auto 0px auto 0px; position: relative; display: block; padding-top: 30px; padding-bottom: 45px; align-content: center">
          <div class="input-group" style="margin-right: 125px; position: relative; display: table; border-collapse: separate">
            <span class="input-group-addon fad fa-file-search" style="display: table-cell; background: #5bc0de; color: white; font-size: 14px; padding: 10px 12px"></span>
            <input [value]="file?.name" class="form-control" readonly type="text" style="text-align:justify; padding: 10px 90px; outline: none; box-sizing: border-box; background-color: #EEE; opacity: 1; border: 1px solid #ccc">
            <label style="opacity: 0; width: 100%; position: absolute; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 999; cursor: pointer; outline: none; background-color: #f9f9f9">
              <input style="position: relative; z-index: 2; float: left; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 0; align-items:baseline; text-align: center" id="fileInput; background-color: #f9f9f9" type="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx" hidden (change)="getFileDetails($event)">
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div style="padding-left: 140px">
          <button (click)="onImportClick()" class="dv-button" style="width: 100px; padding: 4px 6px">
            Import
          </button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




  <footer style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 7px; text-align:center">
    <p>Version 1.0.0 © 2021 DreamVersion, LLC.</p>
  </footer>


</body>

</html>
```

INDEX.HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your snippet provide works as expected. Do you have an error in your HTML or CSS? Run those through a validator.